# How do I update this.context.getConfirmationFromUser and this.context.notify for ReactJS 18? Old code broke upon updating ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have some old code that I didn't write but I'm trying to update it to the newest version of ReactJS (version 18) and I think it was written in 14 or 16. Upon updating ReactJS though, all instances of this.context broke. There's multiple files with this issue, but I'll just post one for simplicity as I imagine the fix will be the same for all of them.

The line that have this.context.getConfirmationFromUser, are now errored because it says the function "getConfirmationFromuser" does not exist on type "unknown".

```
class UpdateContainerComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    uploadingFile: false,
    showSystemStatus: false,
    stagedUpdate: null,
    checkingForStagedUpdate: false
  };

  static contextType = ConfirmationContext;
.
.
.
render() {
    const {
      uploadingFile,
      showSystemStatus,
      stagedUpdate,
      checkingForStagedUpdate
    } = this.state;

    if (checkingForStagedUpdate) {
      return <TextLoadingMessage message="Checking for staged updates..." />;
    } else if (uploadingFile) {
      return <UploadingFileModal />;
    } else if (showSystemStatus) {
      return <SystemStatusModal />;
    } else if (stagedUpdate && stagedUpdate.Contents !== null) {
      return (
        <>
          <StagedUpdateCard stagedUpdate={stagedUpdate} />
          <div className="mt-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <Button
              className="mr-3"
              onClick={() => {
                this.context.getConfirmationFromUser({
                  callback: {
                    method: this.installUpdate
                  },
                  message: (
                    <p>
                      TODO
                    </p>
                  )
                });
              }}
            >
              Install Update
            </Button>
            <Button
              color="light"
              onClick={() => {
                this.context.getConfirmationFromUser({
                  callback: {
                    method: this.deleteUpdateFile
                  },
                  message: (
                    <p>
                      If you delete the update file, you will have to reupload
                      before installing.
                    </p>
                  )
                });
              }}
            >
              Remove Update File
            </Button>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
```

Another one that broke, in the same fashion/error, is this.context.notify, but it's used in similar situations so I won't post the code (don't want this page to be super long).

Any idea what's going on? It looks like there were changes to how context is handled, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Help is much appreciated.